# jmockit seems to not find my non strict expectation, produced result is null

Tags: java, spring, jmockit

I am trying to test the "provisionProduct()" method in some legacy code.  As you can see, it eventually makes a call on productDAO, which I want to mock out.

```
@Service( "productService" )
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class ProductServiceImpl implements IProductService
{
    private ProductDAO productDAO;

    @Autowired
    public ProductServiceImpl(ProductDAO dao)
    {
        productDAO = dao;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public ProductProvisionResponseDTO provisionProduct(Long productId, String serverName) throws PortalException
    {
        [...]
        try
        {
            Product product = productDAO.findProductById(productId);
        [...]
    }
}
```

Here is my test:

```
public class ProductServiceTest
{
    @Mocked
    private ProductDAO m_mockProductDAO;

    private IProductService m_productService;

    @Test
    public void provisionProduct_noProfileAssociatedToProduct_throwsPortalException() throws PortalException, DAOException
    {
        m_productService = new ProductServiceImpl( m_mockProductDAO );

        new NonStrictExpectations()
        {
            {
                m_mockProductDAO.findByProductId( anyLong );
                result = new Product();
            }
        };

        m_productService.provisionProduct( 123456789L, "don't care" );
    }
}
```

When I run the test, the call on productDAO always returns null.

FWIW I can step into the findProductById() method, which takes me into JMockit's RecordAndReplayExecution class.  When JMockit gets to handleInvocation(), the nonStrictExpectation is null, and later produceResult() gives null.

I believe this is a straightforward test case, but I am uncertain about whether Spring is somehow causing undesired effects, which is why I left the various annotations in my code snippets.  Admittedly I'm not very familiar with how Spring works.  I am directly instantiating the ProductServiceImpl, though, so I don't believe Spring is coming into play there.

Any ideas?  Am I missing something totally obvious?

JMockit v1.8, JUnit v4.8.2

Comment: It would possibly be simpler to create a `new MockUp<ProductDAO> () { @Mock public Product findByProductId(long ignore) { return new Product(); } }`

Comment: @assylias I will look into MockUp, but does that mean that I am using JMockit incorrectly?

Comment: if you look at their tutorial, you will see that you can write state or behaviour based tests. Both are valid approaches and quite often both can work. I personally find that the former is easier to use but maybe it's just me.

Comment: The test should definitely work, as it uses the JMockit API correctly. The only discrepancy I see is that "findProductById" is called in the SUT, but "findByProductId" is recorded in the test; it's probably a typo, though.

Comment: assylias, thank you, duly noted.

@Rogério, thank you for validating my usage of JMockit.  This is very disheartening, but in fact it was not a typo (great eye, btw).  For some insane reason, the interface for this ProductDAO has both findProductById() and findByProductId().  I looked just now and they both do the same thing, too.  The perils of working with legacy code, I suppose..  and trusting IDE autocomplete..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The legacy code had two identical methods that were named slightly differently.  I came to realize this when Rogerio noted that my recorded expectation was different from what I was testing.
- My JMockit usage was otherwise correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a method in `JMockit` which could help solve your problem:

[Deencapsulation's setField](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/javadoc/mockit/Deencapsulation.html#setField%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29)

This way you'll tell the JMockit that the null attribute in original class should be replaced by mocked object from test class. I already experienced similar error like you do and this helped me.

Similarly, there is also method `getField`, which helps you to get the value of the current private attribute of the class during the test.